# Error occurs when Save/ Create new transformation file in spoon

Tags: pentaho

I get the following error when save/ Create a new transformation or job in spoon.

> Error reading information from input stream Premature end of file.

To recreate,

> File->New->Transformation  Then click on save

Restarting spoon won't fix this.
When click ok button of the error message everything works fine.

**Pentaho version**: 5.3.0.0-213 

 **OS**: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Detailed error message is attached here.

> 16 11:55:16 - General - ERROR (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from
>   2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) : There was an error while reading
>   the shared objects (continuing load) :
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:  2015/04/16 11:55:16
>   - General - Unexpected problem reading shared objects from XML file : null 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -  2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -
>   Error reading information from input stream 2015/04/16 11:55:16 -
>   General - Premature end of file. 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General - ERROR
>   (version 5.3.0.0-213, build 1 from 2015-02-02_12-17-08 by buildguy) :
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:  2015/04/16 11:55:16
>   - General - Unexpected problem reading shared objects from XML file : null 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -  2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -
>   Error reading information from input stream 2015/04/16 11:55:16 -
>   General - Premature end of file. 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General - 
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -  2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.shared.SharedObjects.(SharedObjects.java:165)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.readSharedObjects(TransMeta.java:3332)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2865) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.(TransMeta.java:2671) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.(TransMeta.java:2623) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.(TransMeta.java:2600) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.(TransMeta.java:2580) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.(TransMeta.java:2545) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.(Trans.java:574) 2015/04/16 11:55:16
>   - General -   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.start(TransGraph.java:3605)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonTransformationDelegate.executeTransformation(SpoonTransformationDelegate.java:880)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$31$1.run(Spoon.java:8548) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1316)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7979)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9310) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:654) 2015/04/16 11:55:16
>   - General -   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 2015/04/16
>   11:55:16 - General -  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General -   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 2015/04/16 11:55:16 -
>   General -     at
>   org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
>   2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General - Caused by:
>   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:  2015/04/16 11:55:16
>   - General - Error reading information from input stream 2015/04/16 11:55:16 - General - Premature end of file.

Comment: you are using community version or enterprise version of pentaho?

Comment: @WorkingHard.. Enterprise Edition

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon Can you try opening a sample transformation and do a save as option and save it with a different name.

Comment: @Pirinthan Yes I tried their sample files. But still the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you please try these steps listed below.
    1.Shutdown Spoon. 
    2.Browse to your home directory [C:\users\xxxx] > go to the .kettle folder   [C:\users\xxxx.kettle] > you should see a shared.xml file.
    3.Rename the shared.xml file to oldshared.xml
    4.Then launch spoon and try it again (creating a new transformation and try saving it).

Comment: works even after 5 years! any idea why this was required (I faced it after chaning pentaho version)